# Azure AD Authentication using Node.js Passport returns 'not supported for this API version'

Tags: node.js, azure, passport.js, adal

I am currently developing an application that utilizes Azure AD for authentication. The application should support multiple tenants, however only a pre-defined list of tenants should be allowed access to the application. Using the [passport-azure-ad](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) library, I added the `OIDCStrategy` to passport as follows:

```
// Use Azure AD OAuth2 strategy.
passport.use('strategyName', new OIDCStrategy({
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/strategyName/callback',
    clientID: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientSecret: 'secret',
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/test.mydomain.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    responseType: 'id_token',
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    skipUserProfile: true
  },
  function (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, done) {
    console.log(profile);
    done();
}));
```

In my routes, I have the following set up:

```
// Authentication endpoint.
router.get('/strategyName', app.passport.authenticate('strategyName'));
router.post('/strategyName/callback',
  function (req, res, next) {
    app.passport.authenticate('strategyName', function (err, account) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(account);
      next(err);
    })(req, res, next);
  }
);
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/strategyName`, I get redirected correctly to the Microsoft login page. However, after authentication, I get this message in the console:

```
{
  "name": "Microsoft OIDC Passport Strategy",
  "hostname": "611b0a5198dd",
  "pid": 60,
  "level": 30,
  "msg": "Body received was:  { error: 'unauthorized_client',\n  error_description: 'AADSTS70001: Application \\'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\\' is not supported for this API version.\\r\\nTrace ID: c8f56153-1125-44ac-af12-55f69b421d36\\r\\nCorrelation ID: d20580ba-75d4-47b9-9497-6a6b02cd72a7\\r\\nTimestamp: 2015-10-20 09:00:15Z' }",
  "time": "2015-10-20T09:00:16.266Z",
  "v": 0
}
```

I have a directory called `test.mydomain.com` added in the Azure Management Portal, and the application is also added.

[image: Azure Screenshot]

Comment: The usage of the function "passport.use" seems to be not correct. The first argument of "use" function should be removed. And the strategy name should be "azuread-openidconnect". Please refer to the README of https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad and the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-node-web/.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT Hi, Passport.js supports named strategies to allow the use of multiple instances of a strategy (see [here](http://passportjs.org/docs/authorize), under 'Configuration' and [this issue](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/50#issuecomment-7568574)). Either way, removing the first argument and changing the strategy name did not help to resolve the issue. Is there any chance that the correlation ID can be used to find out what went wrong?

Comment: @yjwong, please try to change your indidentityMetadata value as  'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Any results, please let me know.

Comment: @WillShao-MSFT Hi Will, I tried with your given identityMetadata and it works as expected (after registering the app on Microsoft Account Developer Center). Any reason why the domain-specific endpoint would not work?

Comment: @yiwong,Azure AD provides a common authentication endpoint where any multi-tenant application can direct sign-in requests, instead of a tenant-specific endpoint. This endpoint is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common for all directories in Azure AD, whereas a tenant-specific endpoint might be https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com. The common endpoint is especially important to consider when developing your application because you’ll need the necessary logic to handle multiple tenants during sign-in, sign-out, and token validation